# How to find key of dictionary with from values for a dictionary with multiple values in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the following way:

```
movieDict[movieID] = (name, np.array(list(genres)),movieNormalizedNumRatings.loc[movieID].get('size'),movieProperties.loc[movieID].rating.get('mean'))
```

which looks like this if I `print(movieDict[1])`

```
('Toy Story (1995)', array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 0.7749140893470791, 3.8783185840707963)
```

How do I find the key-value(in this case it's 1) by just typing 'Toy Story (1995)'?

Comment: This seems like a bad design. If nothing else, why not make a separate `dict` to map from `name` to `movieID` (possibly multiple `movieID`s if names aren't 100% unique), so you can find the `movieID`s in `O(1)`, and only have to do a handful of lookups (usually just one) in `movieDict`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a linear search through all key-value pairs:

```
def find_toy_story():
    for key, value in movieDict.items():
        if value[0] == 'Toy Story (1995)':
            return key
    raise KeyError("Not found!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If `name` is always the first value of the tuple saved in the dictionary values, you can use a dictionary comprehension  to find the items that match the given name:

```
name = "Toy Story (1995)"
{k: v for k, v in movieDict.items() if v[0] == name}
```

But since string is hashable and can therefore be used as dictionary keys it would seem more sensible to construct `movieDict` by using `name` as the keys if possible.